# How to redeploy crashed proxy service on WSO2 ESB

Tags: wso2, esb

I have proxy service on WSO2 Enterprise Service Bus 4.8.1. It makes pass through proxy to Echo service on the same server. After restart ESB server this service disappears because of

```
ERROR - ProxyService Error reading from wsdl URI java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
WARN - Axis2SynapseController The proxy service echoProxy cannot be deployed - Continue in Proxy Service fail-safe mode.
```

I think that internal service Echo is not started when this service starting and it causes this error. When ESB server is completely started Echo servise is running and it is possible to deploy echoProxy service. But I don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your proxy, i believe you used  option. That is why you get that error. If you go to repository/deployment/server/synapse/default/proxy folder, you will see the proxy configuration which you created. You can make a copy from that, and after server starts fine, you can deploy that file in the same location. It will be deployed successfully

Comment: I don't know which option do you mean. I tried move configuration files and after server starts move them back. I works and proxy services was deployed successfully.

Comment: In WSO2 ESB 5.0.0 correct path is `[ESB_HOME]\repository\deployment\server\synapse-configs\default\proxy-services`